# Is it possible to use an alternative to if/else statements in repl python 3.7?

Tags: python-3.7

Is there a better solution in python for making large strings of if/else statements for a random input using import random on version 3.7? I feel like it's a bit counterproductive to write the same if else statements for each input. If not, are there any ways to make my code more efficient?

```
        if G.casefold() == "a":
            Boss_Health = Boss_Health - A
            print("user dealt", A, "damage with A")
            print("Boss health:", Boss_Health)
            print("Health:", Health)
            print("Bosses turn")
            print("")
            G = random.randint(1, 20)

            if G == 1:
                Boss_L = Boss_L + Boss_A
                print("Boss_L has been upgraded by", Boss_A, "and now deals",
                      Boss_L, "damage")
                print("Boss Health:", Boss_Health)
                print("Health:", Health)
                print("users turn")
                str(G)
                G = input()

            if G == 2:
                Boss_Health = Boss_Health + Boss_B
                print("Boss healed", Boss_B, "hp to Boss")
                print("Boss Health:", Boss_Health)
                print("Health:", Health)
                print("users turn")
                str(G)
                G = input()

            if G == 3:
                Boss_M = Boss_M + Boss_B
                print("Boss_M has been upgraded by", Boss_B, "and now deals",
                      Boss_M, "damage")
                print("Boss Health:", Boss_Health)
                print("Health:", Health)
                print("users turn")
                str(G)
                G = input()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the first bit to look for is where there is duplication of code.  In your program, I saw the following lines entered repeatedly:

```
print("Boss Health:", Boss_Health)
print("Health:", Health)
print("users turn")
str(G)
G = input()
```

Those would be a candidate to group into some type of function.  Realizing that the value of "G" gets either a manual entry or a random entry, following is a version of your code with repeated code pulled out and placed into a separate function.

```
import random

def Vitals(b_h, h, rndm = None):        # Separate function to handle repeated statements
    print("Boss health:", b_h)
    print("Health:", h)
    print("Bosses turn")
    print("")
    z = " "
    if rndm == "gen":
        z = random.randint(1, 20)
    else:
        z = input("Enter your choice: ")
    return z

def game_loop():
    A = 1
    G = " "
    Boss_Health = 10
    Boss_A = 2
    Boss_B = 2
    Boss_L = 1
    Health = 20
    while True:
        if G.casefold() == "a":
            Boss_Health = Boss_Health - A
            print("user dealt", A, "damage with A")
            G = Vitals(Boss_Health, Health, "gen")

        if G == 1:
            Boss_L = Boss_L + Boss_A
            print("Boss_L has been upgraded by", Boss_A, "and now deals", Boss_L, "damage")
            G = Vitals(Boss_Health, Health)

        if G == 2:
            Boss_Health = Boss_Health + Boss_B
            print("Boss healed", Boss_B, "hp to Boss")
            G = Vitals(Boss_Health, Health)

        if G == 3:
            Boss_M = Boss_M + Boss_B
            print("Boss_M has been upgraded by", Boss_B, "and now deals", Boss_M, "damage")
            G = Vitals(Boss_Health, Health)

        if G == "q" or G == "Q":
            break
            
        G = Vitals(Boss_Health, Health)
            
    return
    
game_loop()
```

Not having your full program, I improvised to create a user input loop to test this out.  But the net effect is a shorter program that cuts down on repeated code which also reduces the chance of some inconsistencies creeping into the various blocks of code that utilize the function.

Give that a try.

Comment: actually after adding in the other input present in the code the code will not function due to an attribute error: "File "main.py", line 527, in boss
    if G.casefold() == "b":
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'casefold' "

Comment: do you know how I could fix this error?

Comment: You might qualify the values entered or generated as a string (e.g. z = str(random.randint(1, 20)).  Then in the "if" tests make the tests on strings (e.g. if G == "1":).  I just tried that and that worked.